# PHP Fatal error during a DreamFactory installation

Tags: php

I am pulling hairs here and choking kittens with frustration..
Trying to find a nice and easy framework to pull data from a MySQL server to my iOS and Android apps using REST-API and I found this little promising application called DreamFactory.

I had myriad of issues until I finally stumbled on this one while installing:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mcrypt_encrypt() in /opt/dreamfactory/platform/var/www/launchpad/vendor/kisma/kisma/src/Kisma/Core/Utility/Hasher.php on line 501
```

Has anyone encountered this during installation of DreamFactory and can advise me or alternatively another similar application?

Comment: PHP's mcrypt functions are a requirement of a number of popular libraries and frameworks, but not all hosts install them by default. If it's a server you can install packages on, something like `php5-mcrypt` (name will depend on your distro) should do the trick.

Comment: You are missing the mcrypt extension

Answer (score 2):

you can run php -m to list which php modules you have installed.  Here is the link to learn about mcrypt.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

installing with PECL
https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt

installing with homebrew:
https://gist.github.com/teroyks/e0d271e6720eda692456

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Bitnami prepackaged version including stack? It's literally turnkey:

https://bitnami.com/stack/dreamfactory

Comment: I saw it but it didn't suit my needs.. Thanks